# Parsing a file by bytes in Javascript / NodeJS

Tags: javascript, file, parsing, byte

I am very lost in the understanding of reading a file by bytes and converting those bytes to something readable.  I have a .scid file from Sierra Charts, which is a stock / trading platform.  the .scid file contains an array of bar data for a stock chart.  Data structure spec'd here: https://www.sierrachart.com/index.php?page=doc/IntradayDataFileFormat.html

For reference, people that have converted these files in other languages here:

https://gist.github.com/vladaman/8696352

https://www.sierrachart.com/SupportBoard.php?ThreadID=1570

and a sample file of the recent Robinhood stock here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13gqkb4zK51uq8DraKRxCw22u_53_NW4g/view?usp=sharing

Based on the info i have, i assume, i am to read the file, byte chunks, then convert those bytes into the specified types.

Here's is some very very rough test code, just trying to get a basic understanding

```
fs.open('E://SierraChart/Data/hood.scid', 'r', function(err, fd) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    var buffer = Buffer.alloc(1);
    let count = 0
    let header_read = false
    let block = ''
    while (true) {   
        // reading the file, in what i think is byte by byte
        var num = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, 1, null);
        if (num === 0)
            break;
        count = parseInt(count) + 1
        block = block + buffer[0] + ' '

        // per the doc, the first 56 bytes is the header, which we can throw away
        if(!header_read && count == 56){
            header_read = true
            console.log(block + '\n')
            block = ''
            count = 0
        }
        // then a data block is represented in 40 byte chunks
        else if(header_read && count == 40){
            console.log(block + '\n')
            block = ''
            count = 0
        }
    }
    });
```

My output is something like this:

```
// header (56 bytes)
83 67 73 68 56 0 0 0 40 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0        

224 115 51 15 126 161 13 0 0 0 24 66 0 0 24 66 0 0 12 66 52 128 22 66 44 5 0 0 204 234 6 0 252 173 3 0 208 60 3 0 

96 22 202 15 126 161 13 0 225 122 22 66 0 0 33 66 82 184 21 66 194 245 26 66 74 29 0 0 101 126 48 0 139 105 14 0 218 20 34 0 

192 16 93 19 126 161 13 0 143 194 27 66 143 194 27 66 10 215 20 66 71 225 22 66 134 23 0 0 93 247 27 0 5 166 17 0 88 81 10 0 

...
```

which im not sure even looks right.  i would expect the first 8 bytes to look very similar since they're suppose represent a date, in what i believe are 1 minute increments.  from there, im not really sure how to convert those bytes to its other types like floats and ints.

Based on what ive been seen and read, i dont feel like im even on the right track.  im not sure if im even reading the file in correctly or understanding the values going in and out.  this stuff is super confusing.

Answer (score 0):

start your scid file every time with the header bits they give. Theen write your bytes based on the datatype sizes. Yes one can get the date / time through just 1 byte and the the 7 others just have to be left there. Exact sizes are important so use the right data types. Email me if you get seriously stuck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).